# sorting 2 Columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i Have Following Mysql Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  main_Table.id,
  t1.percentage,
  t2.percentage
FROM image_new main_Table
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
    image_colors_new.image_id,
    image_colors_new.percentage
  FROM image_colors_new
  WHERE image_colors_new.s BETWEEN 80 AND 120 AND image_colors_new.h BETWEEN - 20 AND 20 AND image_colors_new.v BETWEEN 73 AND 103
  GROUP BY image_colors_new.percentage
  ORDER BY image_colors_new.percentage DESC) t1
    ON main_Table.id = t1.image_id
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
    image_colors_new.image_id,
    image_colors_new.percentage
  FROM image_colors_new
  WHERE image_colors_new.s BETWEEN - 20 AND 20 AND image_colors_new.h BETWEEN - 20 AND 20 AND image_colors_new.v BETWEEN 85 AND 115
  GROUP BY image_colors_new.percentage
  ORDER BY image_colors_new.percentage DESC) t2
    ON main_Table.id = t2.image_id
```

This Gives me Following Out Put

```
   id   percentage      percentage1
36888   32.975669099756 0.559610705596
54899   9.9722991689751 0.55401662049861
43584   9.9195710455764 9.3833780160858
61517   9.7938144329897 40.20618556701
78076   9.7267759562842 12.786885245902
52123   9.6916299559471 3.3039647577093
36378   9.5798319327731 18.655462184874
43820   9.5238095238095 10.31746031746
53579   9.4736842105263 5.6140350877193
```

but i want rows in following format i.e rows that have percentage with highest value must pop to top, from either of columns

```
id      percentage      percentage1
61517   9.7938144329897 40.20618556701
36888   32.975669099756 0.559610705596
36378   9.5798319327731 18.655462184874
78076   9.7267759562842 12.786885245902
43820   9.5238095238095 10.31746031746
43584   9.9195710455764 9.3833780160858
54899   9.9722991689751 0.55401662049861
52123   9.6916299559471 3.3039647577093
53579   9.4736842105263 5.6140350877193
```

Comment: Probably something like `GROUP BY id ORDER BY MAX(percentage, percentage1)`

Comment: @JanDoggen: That is the problem if already know that then simple order by is the easiest

Comment: @ceejayoz, does MAX really work here, isn't that (only) an aggregate function?

Comment: @jarlh That's why `GROUP BY id`. Turns it into an aggregate without breaking anything.

Comment: Why would 54899 go after 43584 ?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to order by the larger of the `percentage values`.  Add:

```
order by greatest(t1.percentage, t2.percentage) desc;
```

This should actually go in the outer query.  Don't get in the habit of doing `order by` in subqueries.  It might usually work, but there are no guarantees (and this is particularly true in other databases in multi-threaded implementations).

Comment: ORDER BY in sub-queries does however make sense when combined with TOP/LIMIT/FETCH FIRST etc.

Comment: @jarlh: Agreed too, but for my scenario where i simply need kinda max of any of 2 i have this as best case.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: This Is not producing the desired result.

Comment: @temp-learn . . . How is it not working?  Note that you have to put the `order by` in the outer query because the `join`s can and will change the order of the result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff:Mate i didnt said that its not working , it is working but out put is not what i desire. And as you said(quite logically) that the clause should be applied to the outer query, and so it was applied to outer query. I will try to paste the out put below.